# Blazor routing or navigation inside Tab using TreeView control

Tags: asp.net-core, treeview, blazor, tabcontrol

I am unable to achieve a simple routing in Blazor, to illustrate the scenario, I have a tab component containing the Tab control and within one tab item I have a TreeView component containing a TreeView control. Now when I am trying to click on the TreeView item, I am showing the related view of that particular item adjacent to it in the @Body. All looks wired-up but when I click on the TreeView item it shows the view but give me an error along with it.

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'BlazorApp.Pages.TabComponent' does not have a property matching the name 'Body'.

- TabComponent (@page “/tab”) - containing Tab control

  - TreeViewComponent (@page “/tab/treeview”) - containing TreeView control and @Body

    - @Body (@page “/tab/treeview/view1”) to show selected TreeView item (View1) component

**TabComponent.razor**

```
@page "/tab"
@inherits ComponentBase

<BSTabGroup>
    <BSTabList>
        <BSTab>
            <BSTabLabel>TreeView</BSTabLabel>
            <BSTabContent>
                <TreeViewComponent></TreeViewComponent>
            </BSTabContent>
        </BSTab>
    </BSTabList>
    <BSTabSelectedContent></BSTabSelectedContent>
</BSTabGroup>
```

**TreeViewComponent.razor**

```
@page "/tab/treeview"
@layout TabComponent
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="container remove-margin">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <TreeView Data="TreeDataSource" NodeSelected="@TreeNodeSelect"></TreeView>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="card" style="height: 100%">
                <div class="card-header">
                    @Body
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    protected void TreeNodeSelect(object args)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/tab/treeview/view1");
    }
}
```

**View1Component.razor**

```
@page "/tab/treeview/view1"
@inherits ComponentBase
@layout TreeViewComponent

<h1>View 1</h1>
```

I don’t understand why is it complaining to have a Body at TabComponent level which is seemingly unnecessary.

How can I smoothly work out this simple routing?

**EDITED**

The Tab control is from Radzen Blazor library however the TreeView control is custom made by myself.

Comment: Whether you are using some package to create Tab and TreeView or not? If using, it is better to tell us which package you are using, then, we can try to check the document and try to help you. And, you can also check the related official document to learn how to use the related controls.

Comment: @ZhiLv, i have updated my question adding the library reference of tab control and TreeView control is custom made. I don't see any issue with these controls itself because it is straight forward scenario of simple routing and i am using  `NavigationManager.NavigateTo()` function for each treeview node selection.